# FirefoxProfileManager (selenium) not fetching profiles in MAC

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Using below code to open firefox profile, Works file in windows but in Mac. Any help please?
Profile created separately on windows and MAC

Environment - Selenium/C# Windows and MAC

```
        *var options = new FirefoxOptions();
        FirefoxProfileManager profile = new FirefoxProfileManager();
        FirefoxProfile Prof = profile.GetProfile("AutomatedUser");
        options.Profile = Prof;
        IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);*
```

Comment: How did you copy the profile "AutomatedUser" from the Windows to the Mac machine?

Comment: i created profile (AutomatedUser) on both windows and MAC separately.